# Scatter plot Excel: I can't change y-axis font using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a scatter plot using VBA Excel. However, It seems that my code doesn't make any font changes for y-axis. Any thoughts? thanks in advance

```
Sub createmychart()
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        'Chart properties
        'Title Activated, Text, and properties.
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = " Measured data vs Calculated Data" ' Chart Title
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 18
        .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.Underline = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        'X axis title activate, Text, and properties
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "x-Axis"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 16
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Underline = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        'y axis title activate, Text, and properties
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y-Axis"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 16
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Underline = False
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.ColorIndex = 1

        'first Series properties
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values""" 'name of the series
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$d$4:$d$7" ' X values range
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$c$4:$c$7" ' Y values range
            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = 1 'Marker's style 1= Square
            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerSize = 7 'Marker's size
            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2 'Marker's colorfill 2= white
            .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 1 ' Marker's border color 1=black
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$e$4:$e$5"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$f$4:$f$5"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
        .SeriesCollection(2).Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
        .SeriesCollection(2).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 2

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *"my code doesn't make any font changes for y-axis"* - indeed, it doesn't.

Comment: where are your lines `.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 16`, and `.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True` ?

Comment: I believe you refer to this? 'y axis title activate, Text, and properties
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y-Axis"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 16
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Underline = False
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.ColorIndex = 1

Comment: No - read carefully. You're still referring to the **Category** axis in everything apart from the first two lines.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your comment was useful. I m quite a newbie with VBA. thanks alot !